# Replacing a full ORM (JPA/Hibernate) by a lighter solution : Recommended patterns for load/save?

Tags: java, sql, repository-pattern, mybatis, jooq

I'm developing a new Java web application and I'm exploring new ways (new for me!) to persist the data. I mostly have experience with JPA & Hibernate but, except for simple cases, I think this kind of full ORM can become quite complex. Plus, I don't like working with them that much. I'm looking for a new solution, probably closer to SQL.

The solutions I'm currently investigating :

- [MyBatis](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/)
- [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/)
- Plain SQL/JDBC, potentially with [DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) or some other basic utility libraries.

But there are two use cases I'm worrying about with those solutions, compared to Hibernate. I'd like to know what are the recommended patterns for those use cases.

---

#### Use Case 1 - Fetching an entity and accessing some of its associated children and grandchildren entities.

- Let's say I have a `Person` entity.

  - This `Person` has an associated `Address` entity.

    - This `Address` has an associated `City` entity.

      - This `City` entity has a `name` property.

The full path to access the name of the city, starting from the person entity, would be :

```
person.address.city.name
```

Now, let's say I load the Person entity from a `PersonService`, with this method :

```
public Person findPersonById(long id)
{
    // ...
}
```

Using Hibernate, the entities associated to the `Person` could be lazily loaded, on demand, so it would be possible to access `person.address.city.name` and be sure I have access to this property (as long as all the entities in that chain are not nullable).

But using anyone of the 3 solutions I'm investigating, it's more complicated. With those solutions, what are the recommended patterns to take care of this use case? Upfront, I see 3 possible patterns:

1. All the required associated children and grandchildren entities could be eagerly loaded by the SQL query used.

   But the issue I see with this solution is that there may be some other code that needs to access *other* entities/properties paths from the `Person` entity. For example, maybe some code will need access to `person.job.salary.currency`. If I want to reuse the `findPersonById()` method I already have, the SQL query will then need to load more information! Not only the associated `address->city` entity but also the associated `job->salary` entity.

   Now what if there are **10** other places that need to access other information starting from the person entity? Should I always eagerly load *all* the potentially required information? Or maybe have 12 different service methods to load a person entity? :

   ```
   findPersonById_simple(long id)

   findPersonById_withAdressCity(long id)

   findPersonById_withJob(long id)

   findPersonById_withAdressCityAndJob(long id)

   ...
   ```

   But then everytime I would use a `Person` entity, I would have to know what has been loaded with it and what hasn't... It could be quite cumbersome, right?
2. In the `getAddress()` getter method of the `Person` entity, could there be a check to see if the address has already been loaded and, if not, lazily load it? It this a frequently used pattern in real life applications?
3. Are there other patterns that can be used to make sure I can access the entities/properties I need from a loaded Model?

---

#### Use Case 2 - Saving an entity and making sure its associated and modified entities are also saved.

I want to be able to save a `Person` entity using this `PersonService`'s method :

```
public void savePerson(Person person)
{
    // ...
}
```

If I have a `Person` entity and I change `person.address.city.name` to something else, how can I make sure the `City` entity modifications will be persisted when I save the `Person`? Using Hibernate, it can be easy to *cascade* the save operation to the associated entities. What about the solutions I'm investigating?

1. Should I use some kind of *dirty* flag to know what associated entities also have to be saved when I save the person?
2. Are there any other known patterns useful to deal with this use case?

---

***Update*** : There is [a discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jooq-user/26Bd8wnwJgQ) about this question on the JOOQ forum.

Comment: Thanks guys for this very interesting read. Good question and alot of effort from the people answering!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This kind of problem is typical when not using a real ORM, and there is no silver bullet. A simple design approach that worked for me for a (not very big ) webapp with iBatis (myBatis), is to use two layers for persistence:

- A dumb low-level layer: each table has its Java class (POJO or DTO), with **fields that maps directly to the table columns**. Say we have a `PERSON` table with a `ADDRESS_ID` field that points to an `ADRESS` table;
  then, we'd have a `PersonDb` class, with just a `addressId` (integer) field; we have no  `personDb.getAdress()` method, just the plain `personDb.getAdressId()`. These Java classes are, then, quite dumb (they don't know about persistence or about related classes). A corresponding `PersonDao` class knows how to load/persist this object.  This layer is easy to create and maintain with tools like iBatis + iBator (or MyBatis + [MYBatisGenerator](http://www.mybatis.org/generator/index.html)).
- A higher level layer that contains **rich domain objects**: each of these is typically a **graph** of the above POJOs. These classes have also the intelligence for loading/saving the graph (perhaps lazily, perhaps with some dirty flags), by calling the respective DAOs.  The important thing, however, is that these rich domain objects do not map one-to-one to the POJO objects (or DB tables), but rather with **domain use cases**. The "size" of each graph is determined (it doesn't grow indefinitely), and is used from the outside like a particular class. So, it's not that you have one rich `Person` class (with some indeterminate graph of related objects) that is used is several use cases or service methods; instead, you have several rich classes, `PersonWithAddreses`,  `PersonWithAllData`... each one wraps a particular well-limited graph, with its own persistence logic. This might seem inefficient or clumsy, and in some context it might be, but it happens often that the use cases when you need to save a full graph of objects are actually limited.
- Additionally, for things like tabular reports, (specific SELECTS that return a bunch of columns to be displayed) you'd not use the above, but straight and dumb POJO's (perhaps even Maps)

See my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713912/ibatis-domain-modelling/2714302#2714302)

Comment: +1 for a nice answer, specifically for this sentence: *"but it happens often that the use cases when you need to save a full graph of objects is actually limited."*

Comment: No sample application to make your answer very complete? :-) In any case, thanks for the help! +1 indeed...

Answer (score 30):

The answer to your many questions is simple. You have three choices.

1. Use one of the three SQL-centric tools you've mentioned ([MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org), [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), [DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils)). This means you should stop thinking in terms of your OO domain model and Object-Relational Mapping (i.e. entities and lazy loading). SQL is about relational data and RBDMS are pretty good at calculating execution plans for "eager fetching" the result of several joins. Usually, there isn't even a lot of need for premature caching, and if you do need to cache the occasional data element, you can still use something like [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/)
2. Don't use any of those SQL-centric tools and stick with Hibernate / JPA. Because even if you said you don't like Hibernate, you're "thinking Hibernate". Hibernate is very good at persisting object graphs to the database. None of those tools can be forced to work like Hibernate, because their mission is something else. Their mission is to operate on SQL.
3. Go an entirely different way and choose not to use a relational data model. Other data models (graphs for instance) may better suit you. I'm putting this as a third option, because you might not actually have that choice, and I don't have much personal experience with alternative models.

Note, your question wasn't specifically about jOOQ. Nonetheless, with jOOQ, you can externalise the mapping of flat query results (produced from joined table sources) to object graphs through external tools such as [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org). There's an intersting ongoing thread about such an integration on the [ModelMapper User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modelmapper/TYpnSzS-0EY).

(disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)

Comment: Lukas, while I have a huge respect for you (you give so much of your time and JOOQ seems *really* awesome), I think you miss the purpose of my questions : I would *like* to be able to "stop thinking in terms of OO domain model and Object-Relational Mapping" and that's actually why I ask those questions! Loading an entity that has associated entities is a common use case wathever persistence system is used, right? Same thing with saving an entity and its associated entities! I would like to know how people not using Hibernate do those operations! I'd like to see patterns and code samples!

Comment: I think you might be missing the purpose of my answer :-) I just think that there's no better pattern than using Hibernate for *"Loading and persisting an entity that has associated entities"*. Because to be able to do that, you need all the great features that Hibernate offers: Caching, Identity handling, ORM, etc. If you want to solve problems the SQL way, but *still* want to *"save entities and their associated entities"*, then you'll be implementing Hibernate again, in my opinion. But maybe, you didn't want to hear that ;-) Let's see if other opinions appear before this question is closed.

Comment: @electrotype: Note, I've updated the answer with some hint about how to map flat tables to object graphs using third-party tools in jOOQ... Maybe that's a bit more concrete with respect to your question.

Comment: Lukas, if going the "SQL way" means I can't "_save entities and their associated entities_", then what is the SQL way good for? I mean, I work with objects in my Java app, right? Now, I want to load and persist those objects in a database. How do I do? If the "SQL way" doesn't allow me to do that, in a way or another, then why would I even considere using it? I _know_ I won't simply have to write `myObject.save()` like in Hibernate, but what instead? What are the patterns?

Comment: Lukas, your hint about ModelMapper is interresting. I'd like to see a concrete example application (more complex than a simple CRUD) of JOOQ + ModelMapper and how it deals with associated entities!

Comment: @electrotype: As I said. Hibernate solves these patterns very well. If you don't want to use Hibernate, you will wind up implementing something similar like Hibernate on a SQL level - i.e. calculating the delta of changed data in your domain and then generate the necessary CRUD statements in the correct order. SQL is bad at doing CRUD. SQL is good at doing batch operations, querying and data analysis. You've never stated *why* you don't want to use Hibernate, because for *"saving entities and their associated entities"*, Hibernate is really a good choice!

Comment: @electrotype: When I used to solve problems *"the SQL way"*, I had horrible (or awesome from my point of view) 1000-liners as my `SELECT` statements before sending messages back to the database through stored procedures where sophisticated PL/SQL code was executed. About ModelMapper: I don't have real-world examples ready. The current integration is more of an example. I'd be interested myself in seeing the two tools in action. So in that sense: Thanks for the bounty, I'll hopefully learn something from other answers that will be given, here :-)

Comment: Lukas, if I understand what you say, JOOQ can't really be used as a replacement for Hibernate? That if an application has entities with associated children entities (and, well, pretty much _all_ applications out there are like that), then JOOQ is not enough? What are you suggesting then? When does using JOOQ make sense? Do you always use JOOQ *and* Hibernate in your Java applications? Do you only use JOOQ to replace the queries that require _raw SQL_ because they are too complex for Hibernate?

Comment: I don't think *all* applications are like that. In fact, I tend to write applications that don't have a Java domain model. I found it very easy to navigate through relations from the relational data model even in XSLT-generated HTML code. In other words, I'm always operating on tables, not on entities. People have gotten used to JPA but JPA only solves the "domain-model first" approach. Tools like jOOQ are better suited for the "relational model first" approach. Details here: http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/preface. Of course, the world isn't black/white, so you can mix the two tools

Comment: In other words, jOOQ doesn't compete with Hibernate. jOOQ is targeted for people that do not want to build an architecture which Hibernate was tailored for, i.e. a Java domain-model-centric architecture.

Comment: Like the OP I was interested in using jOOQ as a possible replacement for Hibernate mainly because I assumed it would be light weight with no "magic" (more code gen) which is the theme I was looking for when choosing tools for a toy project. But Lukas' comments here made me realize I may have been misguided. Nearly all of the projects I've worked on have a rich domain model. I'm leery of using Hibernate and jOOQ together mainly due to class bloat / compile times. My current project has roughly 800 hibernate entity classes. jOOQ would add around 2400 additional classes (POJOs, tables, and recs).

Comment: @nogridbag: You don't *have* to generate all those objects. You can turn them all off (e.g. turn off POJOS, or turn off POJOS and recs, or even turn off everything and not use code generation)...

Comment: Yeah I know that but those generated classes are what makes jOOQ really appealing to me!

Comment: @nogridbag: That's true. On the other hand, we have customers with far more than that number of generated classes (around 20k). Since jOOQ 3.5, only diffs are re-generated, which improves compilation time. Are you sure that this will be an issue?

Answer (score 11):

**Persistence Approaches**

The spectrum of solutions from simple/basic to sophisticated/rich is:

- SQL/JDBC - hard-code SQL within objects
- SQL-Based Framework (e.g. jOOQ, MyBatis) - Active Record Pattern (separate general object represents row data and handles SQL)
- ORM-Framework (e.g. Hibernate, EclipseLink, DataNucleus) - Data Mapper Pattern (Object per Entity) plus Unit Of Work Pattern (Persistence Context / Entity Manager)

You seek to implement one of the first two levels.  That means shifting focus away from the object model towards SQL.  But your question asks for Use Cases involving the object model being mapped to SQL (i.e. ORM behaviour).  You wish to add functionality from the third level against functionality from one of the first two levels.

We could try to implement this behaviour within an Active Record.  But this would need rich metadata to be attached to each Active Record instance - the actual entity involved, it's relationships to other entities, the lazy-loading settings, the cascade update settings.  This would make it effectively a mapped entity object in hiding.  Besides, jOOQ and MyBatis don't do this for Use Cases 1 & 2.

**How To Achieve Your Requests?**

Implement narrow ORM behaviour directly into your objects, as a small custom layer on top of your framework or raw SQL/JDBC.

Use Case 1: Store metadata for each entity object relationship: (i) whether relationship should be lazy-loaded (class-level) and (ii) whether lazy-load has occured (object-level).  Then in the getter method, use these flags to determine whether to do lazy-load and actually do it.

Use Case 2: Similar to Use Case 1 - do it yourself.  Store a dirty flag within each entity.  Against each entity object relationship, store a flag describing whether the save should be cascaded.  Then when an entity is saved, recursively visit each "save cascade" relationship.  Write any dirty entities discovered.

**Patterns**

- [Lazy Load](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html)
- [Cascading Updates](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/05/30/persistence-patterns-cascading-updates/)
- [Metadata Mapping](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/metadataMapping.html)
- [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)

**Pros**

- Calls to SQL framework are simple.

**Cons**

- Your objects become more complicated. Take a look at the code for Use Cases 1 & 2 within an open source product. It's not trivial
- Lack of support for Object Model. If you're using object model in java for your domain, it will have lesser support for data operations.
- Risk of scope creep & anti-patterns: the above missing functionality is the tip of the iceberg. May end up doing some Reinvent the Wheel & Infrastructure Bloat in Business Logic.
- Education and Maintenance on non-standard solution.  JPA, JDBC and SQL are standards.  Other frameworks or custom solutions aren't.

**Worthwhile???**

This solution works well if you have fairly simple data handling requirements and a data model with a smaller number of entities:

- If so, great!  Do above.
- If not, this solution's a poor fit and represents false savings in effort - i.e. will end up taking longer and being more complicated than using an ORM.  In that case, have another look at JPA - it might be simpler than you think and it supports ORM for CRUD plus raw SQL for complicated queries :-).

Comment: +1: There are a couple of ideas in here that might actually make it into [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org). If a jOOQ query fetches both `Person` and `Address` table records (at least their foreign key / primary key relations), the resulting "jOOQ active records" could reference each other, resulting in transitive `store()` / `refresh()` and other operations... But as you correctly pointed out, there are quite a bit of caveats.

Answer (score 8):

The last ten years I was using JDBC, EJB entity beans, Hibernate, GORM and finally JPA (in this order). For my current project I have returned to using plain JDBC, because the emphasis is on performance. Therefore I wanted

- Full control on the *generation* of SQL statements: To be able to pass a statement to DB performance tuners, and put the optimized version back in the program
- Full control on the *number* of SQL statements which are sent to the database
- Stored procedures (triggers), stored functions (for complex calculations in SQL queries)
- To be able to use all available SQL features without restrictions (recursive queries with CTEs, window aggregate functions, ...)

The data model is defined in a data dictionary; using a model driven approach a generator creates helper classes, DDL scripts etc. Most operations on the database are read-only; only few use cases write.

Question 1: Fetching children

The system is built on a use cases, and we have *one dedicated* SQL statement to get all data for a given use case/request. Some of the SQL statments are bigger than 20kb, they join, calculate using stored functions written in Java/Scala, sort, paginate etc. in a way that the result is directly mapped into a data transfer object which in turn is fed into the view (no further processing in the application layer). As a consequence the data transfer object is use case specific as well. It only contains the data for the given use case (nothing more, nothing less).

As the result set is already "fully joined" there is no need for lazy/eager fetching etc. The data transfer object is complete. A cache is not needed (the database cache is fine);  the exception: If the result set is large (around 50 000 rows), the data transfer object is used as a cache value.

Question 2: Saving

After the controller has merged back the changes from the GUI, again there is a specific object which holds the data: Basically the rows with a state (new, deleted, modified, ...) in a hierarchy. It's a manual iteration to save the data down the hierarchy: New or modified data is persisted using some helper classes with generate SQL `insert` or `update` commands. As for deleted items, this is optimized into cascaded deletes (PostgreSql). If multiple rows are to be deleted, this is optimized into a single `delete ... where id in ...` statement as well.

Again this is use case specific, so it's not dealing with a general approch. It needs more lines of code, but these are the lines which contain the optimizations.

The experiences so far

- One should not underestimate the effort to learn Hibernate or JPA. One should consider the time spent in configuring the caches, cache invalidation in a cluster, eager/lazy fetching, and tuning as well. Migrating to another Hibernate major version is not just a recompilation.
- One should not overestimate the effort to build an application without ORM.
- It's simpler to use SQL directly - being *close* to SQL (like HQL, JPQL) is *not* the same, especially if you talk to your DB performance tuner
- SQL servers are incredibly fast when running long and complex queries, especially if combined with stored functions written in Scala
- Even with the use case specific SQL statements, the code size is smaller: "Fully joined" result sets save lots of lines in the application layer.

Related information:

- [When to use ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11850672/2390083)
- [ANORM is not an object relational mapper](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaAnormt)

Update: Interfaces

If there is a `Person` entity in the logical data model, there is a class to persist a `Person` entity (for CRUD operations), just like a JPA entity.

But the clou is that there is no single `Person` entity from the use case / query / business logic perspective: Each service method defines its *own* notion of a `Person`, and it only contains *exactly* the values required by that use case. Nothing more, nothing less. We use Scala, so the definition and usage of many small classes is very efficient (no setter/getter boiler plate code required).

Example:

```
class GlobalPersonUtils {
  public X doSomeProcessingOnAPerson(
    Person person, PersonAddress personAddress, PersonJob personJob, 
    Set<Person> personFriends, ...)
}
```

is replaced by

```
class Person {
  List addresses = ...
  public X doSomeProcessingOnAPerson(...)
}

class Dto {
  List persons = ...
  public X doSomeProcessingOnAllPersons()
  public List getPersons()
}
```

using use case specific `Persons`, `Adresses` etc: In this case, the `Person` already aggregates all relevant data. Requires more classes, but there is no need to pass around JPA entities.

Note that this processing is read-only, the results are used by the view. Example: Get distinct `City` instances from a person's list.

If data is changed, this is another use case: If the city of a person is changed, this is processed by a different service method, and the person is fetched again from the database.

Comment: Beryllium, very interesting! One question though : are your `interfaces` (for the services or for any other business logic related classes) _clean_? I asked a [similar question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/26Bd8wnwJgQ/n5nwQzKrCNcJ) to Christopher on the JOOQ forum. My concern with playing with "use case specific DTOs" is that the interfaces become a mess! When dealing with an unique `Person` entity (with JPA), any method that needs to do some processing using the person will add `Person` in its signature, not some other close-but-use-case-specific entity. Any comment on that?

Comment: @electrotype I've added an update to the answer. I am not sure, if that answers your question in the comment, just ask again, if something is not clear. And yes, I consider the interfaces to be *extremely* clean.

Comment: "_Each service method defines its own notion of a Person, and it only contains exactly the values required by that use case._". But if a particular service needs to use another service which needs different informations about the `Person`? And if a service used by 10 other services one day requires a new information from the `Person`, should all 10 services and their own "user case specific Person DTO" be modified so they can pass the new required information to the modified service? With a JPA entity it seems easier since each service accesses what it actually needs from it.

Comment: Before I answer your last comment: Could you provide an concrete example for services / properties? Just to make sure that we do not have different meanings for these. Which service is used for which purpose by ten other services? which property is added later and so important that every use case is affected?

Comment: `AdService#isSkipAds(Person person)`, which determines if ads should be skipped or not for the specified person. The previous way to compute this was to check if the person was an admin. Now, the new members (less than 2 weeks) and those from Asia have the ads skipped as well.

Comment: As for the old version: If this function is used in some use cases, you can implement it using a where clause or an outer join to a roles table. If it's used in all/most use cases, this value can be computed once by the login service, and stored in session scope. If the condition is changed later ("new members/Asia"), the where clause/join is replaced by a stored function written in Java/Scala. To "re use" SQL, you can use views. In this case it's not important, but if this value ("skipAds") is available in SQL, the database can sort and paginate on it.

Comment: But generally speaking, the answer in *our* case is "in doubt write more code", because performance has higher priority than comfort, and sometimes there is a price to pay for it. Note that in our case a lot of processing is done in Java/Scala based stored functions used by SQL select, so the DTOs just pass through. Services do not call other services, they are "sealed/self-contained". The controller does one one or two service calls for each request. Do you know how often we have discussed exactly this question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Warning: This is another shameless plug from a project author.

Check out [JSimpleDB](https://code.google.com/p/jsimpledb/) and see if it meets your criteria of simplicity vs. power. This is a new project born out of 10+ years of frustration trying to deal with Java persistence via SQL and ORM.

It works on top of any database that can function as a key/value store, e.g., [FoundationDB](https://foundationdb.org/) (or any SQL database, though everything will be jammed in a single key/value table).

Comment: Its seems that the foundationdb link is broken. The foundationdb link points to foundationdb.org, but this host seems down. But, googling a little, I could find more information about foundationdb at foundationdb.com.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the core issue in the question is with the relational model itself. From what's been described a graph database will map the problem domain very neatly. As an alternative, document stores are another way of approaching the problem because, while the impedance is still there, documents in general are simpler to reason about than sets. Of course, any approach is going to have its own quirks to attend to.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a simple and lightweight library and to use SQL, I can suggest take a look at [fjorm](https://code.google.com/p/fjorm/). It allows you to use POJOs and CRUD operations without much effort.

Disclaimer: I'm an author of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a bit late. Maybe it's worth to have a try. Here is the solution provided by library [abacus-jdbc](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-jdbc):

```
Person person = Person.builder().firstName("jdbc").lastName("whoiam").build();
long personId = personDao.insert(person);

City city = new City(123, "Sunnyvalue");
int cityId = cityDao.insert(city);

Person person = Person.builder().firstName("jdbc").lastName("whoiam").build();
long personId = personDao.insert(person);

Address address = Address.builder().street("1130 Ky").cityId(cityId).state("CA").zipCode("95677").personId(personId).build();
addressDao.insert(address);

Person personFromDB = personDao.gett(personId);
System.out.println(personFromDB);

personDao.loadJoinEntitiesIfNull(personFromDB, Address.class);

System.out.println(personFromDB);
```

Basically you can do CRUD and a lot of more without writing single DAL/DAO method. All the DAO classes you need to define are:

```
public interface PersonDao extends JdbcUtil.CrudDao<Person, Long, SQLBuilder.PSC, PersonDao>, 
                            JdbcUtil.JoinEntityHelper<Person, SQLBuilder.PSC, PersonDao> {
}

public interface AddressDao extends JdbcUtil.CrudDaoL<Address, SQLBuilder.PSC, AddressDao>, 
                                    JdbcUtil.JoinEntityHelper<Address, SQLBuilder.PSC, AddressDao> {
}

public interface CityDao extends JdbcUtil.CrudDao<City, Integer, SQLBuilder.PSC, CityDao> {
}
```

I know it doesn't address all your questions/problems. But at least it provides some alternative approaches for couple of your questions. If you need a framework which provides the extract features you asked, no doubt, that's Hibernate. But sometimes, if you want to control the db operations by a few very simple methods, rather than depend on a framework. Try  [abacus-jdbc](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-jdbc). Here is all the sample code on [Github](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-jdbc/tree/master/samples/com/landawn/abacus/samples/sof/_17860161)

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of [abacus-jdbc](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-jdbc)